# How to write the Extension method for my View using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a output string something like this

```
<*>$<@>%<#
```

I need a extension method for this string as Input

and I need to ass a Space after each > < simbol.

Ouput should be

```
< *> $< @> %< #
```

i need to out put something like this. I need to make sure allways one Space after < > symbol..

Ex: if I get something like this as input < $ i need to leave it as it is...only one space need to be added.

Can any body help me out how to do this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static string KumarsExtension(this string input)
{
    return input.Replace(">", "> ").Replace("<", "< ");
}
```

Comment: Hmm, my answer doesn't really apply now that you've modified the question to specify that you want to use JavaScript rather C#, and need to ensure that only a single space exists after the angled brackets! And I can't do the decent thing and delete my answer because it has been accepted.